# what does grep -v grep do

Tags: shell-script, shell

I'm trying to understand what `grep -v grep` does below:

```
ssh  $server -p $port -o "ConnectTimeout 5" |   grep -v "Connection refused" | grep "Connected to" | grep -v grep | wc -l
```

Or is there a better way to find TCP connection test?

Comment: Please next time consult man pages first. In this case `man grep`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It excludes all lines containing the letter sequence `grep` from the previous pipe output.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check that you can establish a ssh connection within 5 seconds and run a command, just do:

```
if ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=5 -p "$port" "$server" true; then
  printf '%s\n' "$server is up"
fi
```

Your command as it is makes little sense. As you don't provide with a command to run on the remote server, `ssh` will run in the `rlogin` mode, where a pseudo-terminal is requested and the login shell of the remote user is started (or possibly a ForcedCommand).

Then, you're applying several filters to the output:

- `grep -v "Connection refused"`: filter out any line from the *output* that contains `Connection refused`. That makes little sense as that error message if it  appeared would be written on stderr, not the standard output that `grep` is filtering, and also because:
- `grep "Connected to"`: select only the lines that contain `Connected to`. That would also exclude the lines that contain `Connection refused` as it's unlikely for a line to contain both.
- `grep -v grep`, also remove the lines that contain `grep` (so that would be lines that contain both `Connected to` and `grep` and not `Connection refused`!)
- `wc -l`: count the number of resulting lines (so the lines in `ssh`'s stdout that contain `Connected to` except those that also contain `grep` or `Connection refused`). Note that `wc` will only output that number when the connection is closed, when the shell session has been terminated, like when the user enters `exit`. But then again, since the user won't see any output (since it all goes to `wc` eventually), the user will have little clue that he needs to enter `exit` to terminate that session.